# Tag autocomplete list gets cut off by footer

Tags: bug, design, tag-autocomplete

I saw this issue on all sites (excepting (Meta) StackOverflow, and maybe others). Even after Geoff's fix, this still happens in the latest build (`rev 2014.6.12.1658`) on Graphic Design (but *not* here on Meta SE). The following screen shot is taken from graphic design site:

> [image]

#### Steps to reproduce:

1. Open [/questions/ask](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)
2. Type enough content into the body to remove the margin between the preview and footer.
3. Start typing a tag - if there's more than one row of autocomplete suggestions, the list will get cut off by the footer.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't really see where the  problem is? Can you post bigger screenshot with more of the screen and highlight the part that is broken?

Comment: @ShadowWizard You can see even in this screen shot that the description of last 3 tags cannot be read because they are hidden **under** the other elements.

Comment: Can't reproduce, [that's what I see](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7pUZ0.png). What browser then? Is it when asking new question, edit question or editing an answer?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Try to reproduce it on Unix & Linux.

Comment: Right! But that's just one site. Can you see it happening in others? If not, the bug should be reported in the per-site meta.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Same on AskUbuntu, [Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: On AskUbuntu I get a scrollbar on the *Ask a Question* page when the tag box doesn't fit. FF 27

Comment: @Stijn Exactly. But that's also weird. It's not reproducible on all sites. I guess it's just a minor CSS issue.

Comment: OK, fair enough. Let's hope for a quick fix!

Comment: What are you doing to get that small of a margin below the form? What browser + OS are you running?

Comment: @Shog9 It's just the footer of the page - wrote some dummy post content (representing the question content) and chose some tags. Reproduced on `Chromium Version 34.0.1847.116 Ubuntu 14.04 aura (260972)` and `Firefox 30.0` - Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Thanks - that's the bit that was missing. I've reproduced in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: @Shog9 Cool, anyway it's not so major, but it would be great to be fixed.

Comment: @Shog9 Any progress on this?

Comment: Lotta design cleanup happening ATM; probably worth checking back in another month to see if it's still happening.

Answer (score 3):

We've tracked this issue down to a bug that has been present for 2 years.  Our designer has filed for a blame exemption due to the statute of lessitations.

It will be fixed in the next build.

Comment: I see `status-completed` tag, but the problem still exists. When will be the next build?

Comment: Still not fixed, see the [update](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225860/205508).

Comment: Relevant info: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260567/1420197